# open telemetry InMemorySpanExporter not reseting after test case is completed

Tags: python, open-telemetry

Open Telemetry `InMemorySpanExporter` not resetting after test class is complete. This is causing `span_list = self.memory_exporter.get_finished_spans()` to be empty for the 2nd test class.

```
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import SimpleSpanProcessor
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export.in_memory_span_exporter import InMemorySpanExporter
from contextlib import contextmanager
import unittest

tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)


@contextmanager
def method(name):
    with tracer.start_as_current_span(name) as span:
        try:
            yield span
        except Exception as error:
            span.record_exception(error)
            raise
          
          
class OpenTelemetryBase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.tracer_provider = TracerProvider()
        cls.memory_exporter = InMemorySpanExporter()
        cls.span_processor = SimpleSpanProcessor(cls.memory_exporter)
        cls.tracer_provider.add_span_processor(cls.span_processor)
        trace.set_tracer_provider(cls.tracer_provider)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.memory_exporter.clear()

class TestTracing(OpenTelemetryBase):
    def test_method_1(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            with method("TestTracing1") as span:
                raise Exception("Failed trace 1")
        span_list = self.memory_exporter.get_finished_spans()
        self.assertEqual(len(span_list), 1)
        self.assertEqual(span_list[0].status.description, "Exception: Failed trace 1")
        self.assertEqual(span_list[0].name, "TestTracing1")


class TestTracingB(OpenTelemetryBase):
    def test_method_2(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            with method("TestTracingB1") as span:
                raise Exception("Failed traceB 1")
        span_list = self.memory_exporter.get_finished_spans()
        self.assertEqual(len(span_list), 1)
        self.assertEqual(span_list[0].status.description, "Exception: Failed traceB 1")
        self.assertEqual(span_list[0].name, "TestTracingB1")
```

Command to run test class 1 only: `py.test tracing.py::TestTracing`: Executes successfully.

Command to run test class 2 only: `py.test tracing.py::TestTracingB`: Executes successfully.

But command to run both test classes together: `py.test tracing.py`

Output: `tracing.py .F` 1st is successful and 2nd test fails.

`FAILED tracing.py::TestTracingB::test_method_2 - AssertionError: 0 != 1`

Even though I have used the `memory_exporter.clear()` in tera down for each test.

For the `setUpClass` method If i change it to setup then multiple tests inside the same class will start failing, only the 1st one will pass rest will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Srikanth Chekuri beat me to the punch: the basic problem here is that the second call to `set_tracer_provider` doesn't do anything and you end up using the same exporter as in the first setup call.

Unfortunately the tracer provider is global, is only configured once, and the library doesn't provide an easy way to swap out the provider or span processors for tests like these.

Like violence begetting violence, globals beget globals. One (ugly) way around this problem is to make your test exporter a global too, and only attach it to the trace provider when you initialize a test. This means all instances of `OpenTelemetryBase` tests will share the same exporter, so it's up to you to clear the completed spans on teardown, and tests may not work in parallel.

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager
import logging
import unittest

from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import SimpleSpanProcessor
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export.in_memory_span_exporter import InMemorySpanExporter


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Only here for demonstration reasons
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Typically called somewhere else. If this isn't called anywhere we get the
# default ProxyTracerProvider provider, which doesn't support adding span
# processors. This is usually only the case if the OT SDK isn't installed.
trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider())

_TEST_OT_EXPORTER = None
_TEST_OT_PROVIDER_INITIALIZED = False

def get_test_ot_exporter():
    global _TEST_OT_EXPORTER

    if _TEST_OT_EXPORTER is None:
        _TEST_OT_EXPORTER = InMemorySpanExporter()
    return _TEST_OT_EXPORTER

def use_test_ot_exporter():
    global _TEST_OT_PROVIDER_INITIALIZED

    if _TEST_OT_PROVIDER_INITIALIZED:
        logger.info("Skipping repeated call to use_test_ot_exporter")
        return

    provider = trace.get_tracer_provider()
    if not hasattr(provider, 'add_span_processor'):
        logger.warn("OT TracerProvider has no add_span_processor. Is the OT "
                    "SDK installed?")
        return
    provider.add_span_processor(SimpleSpanProcessor(get_test_ot_exporter()))
    _TEST_OT_PROVIDER_INITIALIZED = True


@contextmanager
def method(name):
    tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
    with tracer.start_as_current_span(name) as span:
        try:
            yield span
        except Exception as error:
            span.record_exception(error)
            raise


class OpenTelemetryBase(unittest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        use_test_ot_exporter()
        cls.ot_exporter = get_test_ot_exporter()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.ot_exporter.clear()


class TestTracing(OpenTelemetryBase):
    def test_method_1(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            with method("TestTracing1") as span:
                raise Exception("Failed trace 1")

        span_list = self.ot_exporter.get_finished_spans()
        self.assertEqual(len(span_list), 1)
        self.assertEqual(
            span_list[0].status.description, "Exception: Failed trace 1"
        )
        self.assertEqual(span_list[0].name, "TestTracing1")


class TestTracingB(OpenTelemetryBase):
    def test_method_2(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception):
            with method("TestTracingB1") as span:
                raise Exception("Failed traceB 1")

        span_list = self.ot_exporter.get_finished_spans()
        self.assertEqual(len(span_list), 1)
        self.assertEqual(
            span_list[0].status.description, "Exception: Failed traceB 1"
        )
        self.assertEqual(span_list[0].name, "TestTracingB1")
```

Until the OT python library adds a better way to temporarily replace the tracer provider, or temporarily add span processors or exporters to the global provider, this may be the least invasive way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Your description was not clear but I can share why you are running into `AssertionError`. This is happening because we don't allow setting global tracer provider once it is already set; [link to code which does that](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/blob/main/opentelemetry-api/src/opentelemetry/trace/__init__.py#L470). There can only be one global tracer provider. So, when the call to `trace.set_tracer_provider` made in second test it logs warning without doing anything hence your second attempt to set pipeline was unsuccessful i.e second exporter never received the spans.